# Is there a tool to help me inspect Flex 4 components and change them dynamically?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm looking for a tool that will help me inspect the flex component dynamically, like this tool : http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/ but for Flex 4 (This tool is for Flex 3).

Do you know such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one http://demonsterdebugger.com/